# No puedo instalar Homebrew en macOs High Sierra

Tags: terminal

Trate de instalar Homebrew pero lo unico que pasa es que comienza a instalarse y me dice *"Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort"*. Presiono return y luego solo salta de regreso a una nueva linea, parece que no puede terminar de instalarse o algo asi. Esto es lo que obtengo

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/var
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/homebrew
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/Frameworks

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
MacdeEdu:~ EduardoRamos$
```

Answer (score 0):

ejecuta:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```